# Got SyntaxError: expected expression, got '?' in mains.js, script.js and polyfills.js after migrating to Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

After migrate my app from Angular 13 to 14, and update severals modules, my app builds with no errors, but does not work on the browser. I'm getting this errors on the browser console:
[errors in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8YAm.jpg)
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'
polyfills.js:1:174157
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '?'
scripts.js:1:3308
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '?'
main.js:1:41727

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ngx-admin",
  "version": "4.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve -o",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker": "14.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@nebular/auth": "10.0.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "10.0.0",
    "@nebular/security": "10.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "10.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "13.1.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "14.2.11",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.1.2",
    "@types/xlsx-populate": "git+https://github.com/JanLoebel/types-xlsx-populate.git",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-user-idle": "3.0.1",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "5.0.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "ckeditor": ">=4.11.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.15.2",
    "echarts": "^5.1.2",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.3.2",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "^5.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "leaflet": "1.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-echarts": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-scrolltop": "4.3.0",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.4.1",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "pace-js": "1.2.4",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.10.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.3",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typeface-exo": "1.1.13",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.3.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@juggle/resize-observer": "^3.3.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^4.9.10",
    "@types/d3-color": "3.0.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.21",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "2.2.2",
    "husky": "8.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "4.4.1",
    "rxjs": "7.8.0",
    "stylelint": "14.0.0-0",
    "ts-node": "10.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Don't know which updated package caused the bugs. I've searched and readed several other posts and did not find any solution to this.

[compiled successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STIcU.png)

Comment: given there are only 1985 characters in polyfills.js on the repo referenced, I don't know how there could possibly be an error at character 174157.  Have you modified your files from that repo? Is your project build stream (or the webserver) expanding the "includes"? Use your web browser to download the polyfills.js file from the server and look at character # 174157

Comment: Now I've tested my app with another browser (MS Edge) and works fine. I will update the browser that I was using before (an old Firerox version) and try again. Thanks

Comment: It was a problem with outdated browser. After updating Firefox to the last version all errors are gone and my app its working fine.